# Error in sjp.grpfrq and sjt.grpmean command in sjPlot package. Different result

Tags: r, plot, statistics, sjplot

I am trying to create different kind of variables to teach basic statistic, i am doing analysis considering a numeric variable and a categorical variable. i start creating my variables:

f is the factor and x is numeric.

```
f <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,NA)
x <- rnorm(18,2302,230)
```

Apply the variable labels to the factor

```
l.familiaridad <- c("Muy poco familiarizado",
                    "Poco familiarizado",
                    "Escasamente familiarizado",
                    "familiarizado",
                    "Algo familiarizado",
                    "Bastante familiarizado",
                    "Muy familiarizado")

f <- factor(x = f,levels = 1:7,labels = l.familiaridad)
```

I always use the table() command to do an early review, to check everything is ok.

```
table(f)
```

Then i use the sjPlot to create the html output

```
sjt.frq(f)
```

At this point, everything looks ok. But then i use:

```
sjp.grpfrq(x,f,type="box")
```

as you can see in the plot, "familiarizado" level is showed, but the table() and sjt.frq() command doesnt show anything in that level. And "muy familiarizado" is no showed.

The second error i get is when i use:

```
sjt.grpmean(x,f)
```

i get this error

> Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
>     invalid 'row.names' length

What am i doing wrong? Please help.